# Safari Remote Debugger on iOS 9.3.5 not working in High Sierra

Tags: ios, safari, high-sierra, development

I was just wanting to debug a JavaScript error in one of our pages that occurs for users with iOS 9. So naturally I plugged in an iPad 3 with iOS 9.3.5, opened the page in Safari and connected the remote debugger from a Mac Book running High Sierra.

Problem is, that the content of the debugger stays empty. I can see the debugger UI, but there is no network logs, DOM tree, console output, etc.

This problem occurs on every iPad 3 we own. On an iPad Mini running iOS 10 everything works as expected (but so does our website, so no debugging here).

Is there any way to enable the remote debugger again for iOS 9 devices?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you discovered  anything in the last month?

Comment: No, and I don't think there will be any progress. Apple must have decided to deprecate the iOS 9 support in High Sierra. Luckily we've had another Mac Book running an older Mac OS. I've stuck a "do not update" sticker on it until we deprecate iOS 9.

Comment: I had this too on Mojave and iOS 9 (iPad mini v1). I fixed it (somehow) by opening some other tabs and trying to inspect them. Once one succeeded, they all started working. No idea what's going on.